# Finding how many times a number exists inside an array

Tags: php, regex

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$numbers = array("332467323232", "750327430375", "332503248632", ...);
```

I would like to get the number of times that the number **32** (or any other number) is showing up in every string inside my array.

Example:

```
$times = array(4, 1, 3, ...);
```

Comment: There is. Is there a reason why you must use regex?

Comment: I CAN do it using php, however, regex is a shorter and cleaner approach .

Comment: I can't say I understand exactly what you want to use regex for here. would 3245 imply that the number 32 appears? Would that also mean you wish to count 324, 3245, 245, 45, etc? Regex is a way to match, validate and replace, but counting isn't really its strong suit.

Comment: 3245 apply that the number 32 is appearing 1 time.

Comment: Alright, I just understood your example output. @Jon's answer would be better for this than regex in any case.

Comment: @Lior: Regex is not cleaner, and I have no idea why you think it's going to be faster. It's guaranteed to be slower because it's a much more powerful tool. You don't need that power here.

Comment: @Jon I'm willing to test it when I'll find the way of doing it with regex. I'll post my results here. You might be right but I'd like to test it

Comment: @Lior: The same method I give but with `return preg_match_all('/32/', $str)` inside the anon function.

Comment: @Lior: You say "regex is a shorter and cleaner approach" but haven't actually shown us code that validates that conclusion.

Comment: @AndyLester usually regex is shorter and cleaner since you need less lines of code but to test it I need the regex answer. Anyway, I didn't ask the right question and I'm going to post it again. Take a look at my comment to Jon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct answer:**

```
$times=array_map(function($str) { return substr_count($str, "32"); }, $numbers);
```

Initial answer (wrong, misread the question, sorry!):

Here's an one-liner which does not use regular expressions:

```
echo array_sum(array_map(
                  function($str) { return substr_count($str, "32"); },
                  $numbers));
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer but I didn't ask my question properly... I'm looking for the numbers of time that 32 is appearing assuming the string in my array is divided by commas. exp. "32,53" gives 1 appearance but "43,27" giving 0. I'll post a proper question. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might not need regex, for example:

```
$numbers = array(
    32323232, # 4
    12233232, # 2
    12314232, # 1
    12349085, # 0
);

$result = array();

foreach($numbers as $num){
    $result[] = substr_count("$num", '32');
}

print_r($result);

//  Array
// (
//     [0] => 4
//     [1] => 2
//     [2] => 1
//     [3] => 0
// )
```

This should do what you're looking for. [substr_count on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)